# How to run query with Jongo to get records between given days?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, jongo

Using Jongo API to query MongoDB, I can fetch documents from last 5 days with

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
employees.find(
  "{ createdOn: { $gt:  # } }", 
  cal.getTimeInMillis() - 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
);
```

I would like to know how to query records in time interval `(5 days from now, 3 days from now)`.

Assuming today is Aug 9, I need records from 4th to 6th Aug.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://jongo.org/#querying), with Jongo API you can pass multiple parameters to your query as

```
employees.find(
  "{ createdOn: { $gt: #, $lt: #  } }",
  nowInMs - 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, 
  nowInMs - 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
);
```

that will find documents with `createdOn` field in time interval `(5 days from now; 3 days from now)`.

Comment: You are great as usual tarshypka